# My wordpress frontend does not update when I make changes to the backend

Tags: wordpress

my page looks the same when I update the page, I mean it is not updated with the changes.
I'm triyng to load the page in incongnito with no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a plugin like wp-rocket or similar try to clear cache there, in the worpress backend

Comment: The OP already stated they are using “incognito” mode in Google Chrome, which does not retain any local cache outside of assets cached during the incognito session.

Comment: you right, I edited the answer